# Kendo grid data("kendoValidator").validate() method always returns true

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

`$("#mygrid").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator").validate()` method always returns true even if there are validation errors for some of the input fields in the grid. On first time load the validation works fine but during edit the next time it does not show the tooltip, please help me resolve this issue.

I have added a validation template using schema of the grid:

```
schema: {
    model: {
        id: "AuctionID",
        fields: {
            AuctionID: {
                editable: false,
                type: "number"
            },
            AuctionName: {
                type: "string",
                validation: {
                    required: { message: "An Auction Name is Required!" },
                    validateAuctionName: function (input) {
                        if (input.attr("data-bind") == "value:AuctionName") { // check if this is the element to validate
                            alert(input.val().length);
                            if (input.val().length > 10) {
                                input.attr("data-validateAuctionName-msg", "AuctionName can only have a maximum of 10 characters.");
                                return false;
                            }
                            else
                                return true;
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At what point would you like your validation to be triggered? Surely it shouldn't be on initialisation of the grid.

Comment: My grid editing mode is inline so on click of the update button I wanted the tooltip to showup for all invalid enteries, so I have added if($("#mygrid").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator").validate()) in the edit event of the grid to check if validation fails but this returns true always. If this is false then I can use app.alert() to display the tooltip, this is working fine. I have not added any rules within the validator, I have used only the grid schema for validation.

Comment: Have you had a look at this? http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-custom-validation.html.

Comment: In the demo, they are not using any events, I have added an edit event in that I am using this method if($("#mygrid").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator").validate()) to check if all validations are passed

Comment: In the demo, the validation is triggered on update/edit. Unless you set up a fiddle there is so little I can do to help coz I can't see a working example

Answer (score 2):

The method you are using is not triggering validation as it interrogates "this" and validates it if it is a kendo widget with validation enabled.

I found this way to force validation - get hold of model and trigger change on property you want to validate:

```
model.trigger("set", { field: "FinishTime", value: model.FinishTime });
```